# Highlight all text between brackets?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

`set showmatch` highlights matching brackets. Is there a way to highlight *all text* between brackets? I have a black background. When I land on a bracket, I'd like to change the background of the in-between text to dark gray.

Answer (score 1):

This approach isn't automatic, but `v%` should show you the text (and conveniently select it in visual mode for further processing).

Alternately, you could use an autocommand or mapping to create a `textprop` or similar to highlight the region of interest, and then use a timer to clear it (if desired). See `:help searchpairpos()` for a helpful function to get data about the region to highlight.

Answer (score 0):

It does what it says to do: show (briefly) matching parens/brace/bracket/anglequote.
What you're asking for (highlight all text within delimiter) is something very different... Maybe activate search highlight with `se hls` then issue a relevant search?